# How to compare two cold Observable's sources (not the potential streams they emit)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6

**Scenario:** I am using publishReplay to cache and replay certain Http requests within an Angular application (using publishReplay over shareReplay due to some bugs that have since been fixed in rxjs).

My problem is that I want to force the cached observable source to update itself and create a new cached observable with publishReplay if I detect a URL parameter change. I thought perhaps this could be accomplished by interrogating/comparing the newly proposed observable with the existing cached observable's source, but I have been unsuccessful in achieving this.

**What I am looking for:**  A way to either interrogate an observable's source so I can compare it to the source of another observable to see if they are identical (url in this case), or some other means of detecting the url on an Http Observable changed with publishReplay. Furthermore I am attempting to abstract this logic away into a caching mechanism so I don't have to sprinkle code throughout the apps that detects if the parameter changes.

Here is a very naive example of what I'd like to do that isn't working, the input source parameter is the new Observable which contains a handle to an http request, and the origSource is the previous observable which contains the same (though potentially with a different url parameter that publishReplay doesn't seem to acknowledge).

```
  // determine if key exists and source is un-modified (i.e params did not change)
protected isEntreeValid<T>(key: ICacheKeyConstantsModel, source: Observable<T>): boolean {
    if (!this.has(key)) { return false; }
    if (this.has(key)) {
        let origSource = this.cache.registry.get(key).source; // observable previously cached used to resubscribe to later and returned cached publishReplay response, or can be tickled to make the original http request again effectively busting the cache.
        console.log('source: ', source);
        console.log('are they equal', source.source === origSource.source); //always returns false but assume need to check some inner value of observable anyways and do a fuzzy comparison.
        if (source.source !== origSource.source) { return false; }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Above Method:** The input 'source' param in above method is just a pointer to an http.get method and stored in a Map in key/value pair fashion: 
i.e. Map 
so that we can marshal their caching state and other attributes in a centralized way more easily. Basically it is here that if a 'key' already exists I'd like to evaluate 'source' to see if parameters on the URL changed so if they have we can bust the cache, alternatively if they haven't we'll just return the publishReplay result.

**Note:** I do not intend/want to connect to the Observable in this case, I am interested only in comparing the source of these Observables, not the potential streams they will emit.

**Update:** Found what I was looking for, though not sure why it is WAAAY down there. Is there a slick way of iterating down to this, seems consistent structurally with Observables and not an artifact of something weird I did when creating these ones. Seems odd indeed that this very basic info would be so far down in there (note url has been obfuscated and this example didn't have params):

**Property location is:** Observable.value.source.source.source.source.source

**Structure of object at this location is:**

{

```
value: HttpRequest

body: null

headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}

method: "GET"

params: HttpParams {updates: null, cloneFrom: null, encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec, map: Map(0)}

reportProgress: false

responseType: "json"

url: "https://my-dev-server.com/primary/HealthCareApp/Patients"

urlWithParams: "https://my-dev-server.com/primary/HealthCareApp/Patients"

}
```

**Question:** Any clean/reliably ways to flatten, or drill-down to the inner most Observable without subscribing?

**Update 2:**

For now I'm using a method like the one below to extract the innerObservable, there are probably better ways but here's what we're rocking with for the time being:

```
// retrieve inner meta-data from cold observable for interrogation without subscribing
private extractInnerObservable<T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    let target = observableOf(source)['value'];
    while (target['source']) {
        target = target['source'];
    }

    return target;
}
```

**Resulting Method:**

[image]

Conclusion: Still open to exploring other options for sure, but I’ve updated this question multiple times to share where I’m at as am at least in a state now where it addresses the original problem (though certainly not in the most elegant fashion). However Incase someone else is struggling with something similar thought there would be value in sharing the result of where some of this madness ended up.

Comment: Thank you for scrubbing my question for me R. Richards. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: Hmm, I'm curious as to why do you need to cache observables instead of values? Also, I'm pretty sure it's less likely that `source` would ever be the same reference as `origSource` since they represent different instances created by the same class.

Comment: I use the cached observable to store particular http configuration across several modules, but I agree that comparison would never work in my sample because they will be different object references. I should not have included that. What I expected to be more likely would be a comparison of a specific property and maybe even a value comparison since as you indicated the pointer-references most likely would never be the same

Comment: Updated the snippet in the question to remove the object reference compare as that was misleading.

Comment: I think there are better approaches to this than inspecting the observable itself. can you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to do in more of a pseudo code fashion?

Comment: I don't doubt this at all - basically the first snippet is kinda the gist of it except it now is comparing the URL props on the source to see if they changed, but i'll try to distill it down further for easy consumption, gimme a few.

Comment: It’s not pseudo core, but that last screenshot is pretty concise and I think sums up the context are of what was trying to be achieved. I guess more context as to how the cache is created and managed wouldn’t hurt but figured I’d start here. If more context/code would be beneficial please let me know and I’ll do what I can to accommodate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue to invert your logic here. if there's some param coming through that you want to change the cached request on, then use operators to do it...

```
private paramSource = new Subject<string>(); // whatever type is appropriate
cached$ = this.paramSource.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(), // could add some custom compare function in here
  switchMap(param => this.makeRequest(param)),
  shareReplay(1) // whatever you wana do for caching
);

// call this whenever you might've wanted to run the observable inspection
updateParam(param: string) {
  this.paramSource.next(param);
}
```

not positive if this achieves your goals directly, as I'm alittle unclear on what you're after, but hopefully this is close.

Comment: I'll check this out in a bit - thanks. In a nutshell I want to see if a URL (or parameters of a URL) for an Observable changed without making an HTTP request.

Comment: Hey bryan60, day kinda got away from me so I will be unable to play with this more until tomorrow or over the weekend. In meantime wondering if with the proposal you’ve made, are you envisioning we can evaluate the source without subscribing the http call? I ask because one of the key constraints is to evaluate the observable.source meta-data without subscribing/piping since they are HTTP requests. 
This has me hoping to observe the source meta-data (I.e. an object with a URL property) without actually “heating up” the http observable, but maybe that not what u had in mind at all?

Comment: I'm proposing to not try to evaluate the source at all, it's usually a bad sign when you're inspecting an observable like this. you evaluate the inputs used to build the source and only change the source when the inputs change. whether the observable is hot or cold is irrelevant to this method. works fine either way. the only change you might need is to make `paramSource` to a `ReplaySubject` instead but I'm not sure that's needed, depends on the specifics

Comment: gotcha - this looks like a valid approach, just wanted to make sure the intent wasn't to fire the http request just to evaluate the input change. Thanks again.